# How to compare multiple HTML classes in TagHelper Unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a TagHelper for a link in which two HTML classes has been added

```
output.AddClass("body", HtmlEncoder.Default);
output.AddClass("link", HtmlEncoder.Default);
```

Then there is a UnitTest for the same TagHelper where I am comparing the classes

```
output.Attributes.ShouldContain(new TagHelperAttribute("class", "body link"));
```

I have tried comparing as per below as well

```
output.Attributes.ShouldContain(new TagHelperAttribute("class", "body"));
output.Attributes.ShouldContain(new TagHelperAttribute("class", "link"));
```

But test fails with the below error

```
output.Attributes
    should contain
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute (1179098850)
    but was actually
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute (-373750961), Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute (1870575232), Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute (-1866101448)]
```

If anybody can provide some help on this would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to make it work

```
var classAttribute = output.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "class");
classAttribute.Name.ShouldBe("class");
classAttribute.Value.ToString().ShouldBe("body link");
```